# awesome wm with xubuntu - setting wallpaper resets to default

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background, awesome, xdg

I am using awesome v3.4.15 (Never Gonna Give You Up) and (X)Ubuntu. My display manager is `lightdm`.

In `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua` I've added this line to change my background to a solid color:

```
theme.wallpaper_cmd = { "hsetroot -solid '#000000'" }
```

However, my wallpaper is always set to the [default blue wallpaper](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-XqVE_wCzNdc/UmGgfey1xkI/AAAAAAAABak/_S0l4DWqC_c/s630-fcrop64%3D1,00002aaabe95d7ea/xubuntu-saucy.png) on a reboot - even after pressing <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, which [reloads the config file by restarting awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Getting_started#Basic_mappings).

When I execute `hsetroot -solid '#000000'` itself, it works like a charm. Reloading the config doesn't change anything, the background then stays the desired fixed color.

To reload my config, I've got the default command in my `rc.lua`:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "r", awesome.restart)
```

---

My greeting login screen, which has the same wallpaper as the default blue desktop, is specified in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf` and contains a line saying where this wallpaper is stored:

```
[greeter]
background=/lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/wallpaper.png
#background=#000000
```

I changed it from `#000000` back to the default `[...]/wallpaper.png`, after I've found out that switching from my user to guest/other [in the menu of the said greeter](http://smdavis.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/greybird-gtk31.png) resulted in the wallpaper being switched to a black wallpaper - the one specified in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf`.

This is weird, because why doesn't this happen, when I select my user name in the menu, but with all other accounts?

If I switch the `background` setting back to the default value `[...]/wallpaper.png`, then selecting guest/other accounts in the menu results in the wallpaper being shown. It has a minor difference, though, to the default blue wallpaper I am having trouble with getting rid off: It doesn't have the weird 6-dots logo, which can be seen [here again](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-XqVE_wCzNdc/UmGgfey1xkI/AAAAAAAABak/_S0l4DWqC_c/s630-fcrop64%3D1,00002aaabe95d7ea/xubuntu-saucy.png). So it is just the raw picture, that is located at `/lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/wallpaper.png`.

1. Why doesn't my background change to black, when setting `background=#000000` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf`?
2. Where does this extra 6-dots logo come from?
3. Why is my config not reloaded when pressing <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, resulting in the wallpaper_cmd to be executed?
4. Other than `awesome.restart`, how can I reload my awesome config to test it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the four questions I'm afraid.

Your problem is that the colour reverts on restart? And that running the command:

```desktop
theme.wallpaper_cmd = { "hsetroot -solid '#000000'" }
```

sets it to black corectly.

Have you tried adding a `.desktop` file in `/home/<USER>/.config/autostart`?

Run these commands:

```desktop
mkdir .config/autostart
```

(don't worry if it says `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘autostart’: File exists.` That means it was already there).

```desktop
cd .config/autostart
touch background-setter.desktop
gedit background-setter.desktop
```

In the file should be the following:

```desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Background Setter
Comment=Set background
# the sleep and extra command is to ensure it runs, and then runs again incase there is another startup program that is breaking the settings.
Exec=theme.wallpaper_cmd = { "hsetroot -solid '#000000'" }; sleep 6; theme.wallpaper_cmd = { "hsetroot -solid '#000000'" }
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Then make it executable

```desktop
chmod +x background-setter.desktop
```

It should launch on startup.

Answer (score 0):

You mention editing `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua`. This is the global/default awesome config (which gets overwritten on updates btw). Your personal config at `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua` gets used first. Edit this file and it should stick.

haven't got a clue about the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I use exactly the same configuration as you (Awesome inside XFCE).

To resolve this issue, I think you need to remove at least the `xfdesktop4` package. When I look at my config, I also removed the `xubuntu-desktop` package. I didn't remember if both removals are needed.

One or two of these packages override the awesome desktop configuration. I think this is surely why you think your configuration is not updated / reloaded.

Commands to remove the packages :

```
sudo apt-get remove xfdesktop4
sudo apt-get remove xubuntu-desktop
```